# updating boolean value in spring data jpa using @Query, with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have spring-data and hibernate configured and running. I can save records using spring-data but for some reason I am not able to run query that will update all Boolean fields in a table.

I tried this:

```
@Query("update Content v set v.published = false where v.division = :division and v.section = :section")
void unPublishContent(@Param("division") String division, 
                         @Param("section") String section);
```

I also tried this:

```
 @Query("update Content v set v.published = 0 where v.division = :division and v.section = :section")
void unPublishContent(@Param("division") String division, 
                         @Param("section") String section);
```

Parameters division and section are coming true but no change on the table.

p.s. I am also using mysql database.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I'm using Spring 3.1 and Spring JPA Data. I was having a similar problem. I was constantly getting an error while trying to update multiple records in 1 query.

So, I had something like this.

```
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.state = ?1 WHERE u.server.id = ?2")
public void updateAllUsers(long state, long serverid);
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations
```

So, after googling for a while, I found out that you had to add @Modifying.

```
@Modifying  
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.state = ?1 WHERE u.server.id = ?2")
public void updateAllUsers(long state, long serverid);
```

But then I was getting the following error:

```
...    
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; 
nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
...
```

So, I figured my problem was now a transaction problem and I went back to google to research it and found out that you have to add @Transactional now. It appears that @Modifying also requires @Transactional.

```
@Modifying  
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.state = ?1 WHERE u.server.id = ?2")
public void updateAllUsers(long state, long serverid);
```

but then I got the following error:

```
No value for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource (...) ] bound to thread
```

Again I googled for a while and came to the conclusion that my configuration was wrong and it turned out to be true. I was missing some xml configs.

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

It was long journey but I finally got it working. I hope this will help someone, trying to "pay it forward" as many others have helped me with their wonderful blogs, answers and comments.

Comment: <tx:annotation-driven /> should not be necessary as Spring Data automatically applies annotation based transactions to the repository interfaces.

Comment: also make sure the annotation is imported from org.springframework.transaction.annotation not javax

Comment: PERFECT ANSWER !! Thank's a lot !

Answer (score 10):

To execute modifying queries you need to annotate the method with an additional `@Modifying` as outlined in the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries) like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Content v set v.published = false where v.division = :division and v.section = :section")
void unPublishContent(@Param("division") String division, 
                     @Param("section") String section);
```

Comment: So… did that work for you or not? I am a bit puzzled what you're saying ;)

Comment: sorry oliver, was bit tired and I made a typo. No it did not help. Form what I understand is that this option "@Modifying" is useful if your repository is annotated with read only. In that way you can have I repository that is mainly read only but, it still allows you to have write methods in it.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with `readOnly` - at least not directly. `readOnly` is about transactions, `@Modifying` is about a call on the `EntityManager`. Of course it doesn't make sense to try to execute a modifying method in a read-only transaction.

Answer (score 8):

For me too, it worked with following annotations:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.active=1 where a.id=?1")
@Transactional
void  activeUser(Long id);
```

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked with following annotations :

```
@Modifying
@Query("update JsonContactImport x set x.isImported = true where x.id in :ids")
@Transactional
void updateImported(@Param("ids")  List<Long> ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with Spring 5, @Transactional annotation is still required.

```
@Repository
public interface DoorStyleRepository extends JpaRepository<DoorStyle, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE DoorStyle ds SET ds.enabled = false")
    void setEnabledFalse();
}
```