# "Not supported for DML operations" with simple UPDATE query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I'm getting the error `Not supported for DML operations` when I use the following HQL...

```
@Query("UPDATE WorkstationEntity w SET w.lastActivity = :timestamp WHERE w.uuid = :uuid")
void updateLastActivity(@Param("uuid") String uuid, @Param("timestamp") Timestamp timestamp);
```

What could be causing the issue?  It doesn't seem to be a common error given the few results I've found in Google.

Comment: can you provide code full listing and the stack trace.

Comment: Look at the accepted solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12426144/172306 looks similar.

Comment: +1 for "@Modifying" 
(from your own comment in the answer of Ajay Bhojak)

Your should add this as the default answer, as this is supposedly a spring JPA Repository question, you were questioning

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check the post [hibernate hql ERROR: Not supported for DML operations](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2465847) in the hibernate users forum.

Most likely you called

```
querySt.list();
```

for your `UPDATE` query. Instead you should call

```
querySt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I just solve the same problem by adding the Modifying annotation. One more hint: the function return type must be void, because I copied the function from a normal query function so the return type was List<SomeModelClass>, then I have the same error even after I added Modifying annotation.

Comment: @cn123h had the same problem, copy paste had the return type as List<T> instead of void

Answer (score 16):

I was also having the same problem with annotations.After searching and doing some tricks I was able to solve it.
There are some below steps which you need to verify while using DML operation with JPA.

1. Use anotation
   `@Modifying(org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying)` and `@Transactional(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)` on required method.
2. Use `void` as return type of method.

e.g:-

````java
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE ProcedureDTO o SET o.isSelectedByUser =?1")
@Transactional
public void getListOfProcedureBasedOnSelection(Boolean isSelected);```
````

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same problem, in my case I had to only add `@Modifying` annotation. According to documentation:

> Indicates a query method should be considered as modifying query as that changes the way it needs to be executed. This annotation is only considered if used on query methods defined through a Query annotation. It's not applied on custom implementation methods or queries derived from the method name as they already have control over the underlying data access APIs or specify if they are modifying by their name.
> Queries that require a `@Modifying` annotation include INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and DDL statements.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your service class method which calls `updateLastActivity` has `@Transactional(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)` annotation. and modify the repository method to below,

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
...
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE WorkstationEntity w SET w.lastActivity = :timestamp WHERE w.uuid = :uuid")
void updateLastActivity(@Param("uuid") String uuid, @Param("timestamp") Timestamp timestamp);
```

For more insights please use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47066201/3168721).

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me because, being q an object of class Query, q.list() is not to be used for updates or deletes, but q.executeUpdate()