# org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateQueryException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I am trying to update a record in the database and I getting this error

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateQueryException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE com.xxx.models.User u set u.notifiable = true WHERE u.emailAccess = :emailAccess AND u.isAdmin = false]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE com.xxx.models.User u set u.notifiable = true WHERE u.emailAccess = :emailAccess AND u.isAdmin = false]
```

This is my hql attempt

```
@Modifying
    public User updateUser(String emailAccess) {

        String hql = "UPDATE User u set u.notifiable = true WHERE u.emailAccess = :emailAccess AND u.isAdmin = false";
        return (User) _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("emailAccess", emailAccess).list();

    }
```

After researching, I added the @Modifying annotation to the top of the method but the error still persists. Please what could be wrong?

Comment: in your return statement I see **.list()** and you are returning just one user. Is it correct?

Comment: use 'executeUpdate()' instead of 'list'
same issue here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622147/not-supported-for-dml-operations-with-simple-update-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Modifying` is a Spring Data annotation and you do not appear to be using Spring Data so that is of no use to you.

You need to call `executeUpdate()` and make the return method void as executeUpdate

> Returns: The number of entities updated or deleted..

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#executeUpdate()

or return the result of a second query.

```
public void updateUser(String emailAccess) {

    String hql = "UPDATE User u set u.notifiable = true WHERE u.emailAccess = :emailAccess AND u.isAdmin = false";
    _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("emailAccess", emailAccess).executeUpdate();

}
```

Comment: Cannot cast from int to User. In respect to your solution

Comment: As the API docs state executeUpdate() returns The number of entities updated or deleted so an int and not a User.

Comment: What exactly is missing from it?

Comment: public void updateUser(String emailAccess) {

        String hql = "UPDATE User u set u.notifiable = true WHERE u.emailAccess = :emailAccess AND u.isAdmin = false";
         _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("emailAccess", emailAccess).executeUpdate();

    }

Comment: @Francis your logic is wrong. Your method can't return a particular user anyway. If you're running `update` statement you do not know how many rows in DB will be updated

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but can i add a return statement to void

Comment: replace the void return type with int

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke `executeUpdate()` on your query when you're going to update or delete your entities.

`list()` method which you're using is to select entities by given query, not to update them.

Your method signature and return types are incorrect. You can never be sure that `update` operation will actually update only a particular user. `executeUpdate()` method returns number of rows affected by your query, not the updated entity.

Moreover even `list()` from your original answer won't return a particular user. It (in case of select query) will return a list of users according to your conditions.