# JPA update Query issue

Tags: java, jpa

Suppose we have 2 entities

```
@Entity(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User{

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Long id;

 private String name;
}
```

Another Inherited Class

```
@Entity
public class ExtendedUser extends User{
   private String bio;
}
```

Now when i try to run a JPA Update query

```
@Modifying
@Query("update ExtendedUser  set bio=?2 where id=?1")
void updateOverflowText(Long id,String bio);
```

I get an exception, cannot run the query, due to ambiguous column "id"

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2450)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2371)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2355)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.MultiTableUpdateExecutor.execute(MultiTableUpdateExecutor.java:142)
 ... 103 more
```

Comment: Try as `update ExtendedUser usr  set usr.bio=?2 where usr.id=?1`

Comment: tried. But it did not work

Comment: What if you execute the same update statement in backend with values to see it works fine.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220262/updating-boolean-value-in-spring-data-jpa-using-query-with-hibernate) may help you.

Answer (score 3):

try this

> update User usr set usr.bio=?2 where usr.id=?1

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@Modifying 
@Query( nativeQuery = true, value = "update user set bio=?2 where id=?1")
int updateOverflowText( Long id, String bio );    `
```

Comment: I don't know, somehow answers beginning with "try" give me the feeling that the author is not sure about the effect the proposed change will have. Anyway, I would feel more confident if you added an explanation why your solution will fix the problem. - Having said that, welcome to stack overflow and thanks for sharing your knowledge :)

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?