# Deleting row is database

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

```
@Query("delete from MyClazz a where c.id in (?1)")
void deleteData(List<Long> ids);
```

Executing this query is giving the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [delete from MyClazz a where a.id in (:x10_)]
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:306)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution
```

How can I pass list parameter in Query?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Its not duplicate!I am passing list as a parameter.

Comment: Edit the question to explain the difference.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Clearly its not that we cannot row by `in(...)` and not duplicate too as suggested by you.So its a request plz read the question and check how exactly its is same as the one you are marking as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the annotation `@Modifying` on the delete method.
Also take a llok at this [updating boolean value in spring data jpa using @Query, with hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220262/updating-boolean-value-in-spring-data-jpa-using-query-with-hibernate)

Comment: @ Anarki Thank you so much!damn how can I miss @Modifying..so stupid of me..